# android Local variable not used from Switch

Tags: android, variables, switch-statement

Why I get two warnings: that variable "input5" is not used, and when I want to use it later in Intent: "input5" cannot be resolved to variable.

What am I missing in between? Thanks!

```
    final Switch mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.edit_home);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){
                 **double input5 = 1;**
                }else{
                 **double input5 = 2;**
                }

    Button buttonForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToMain2);
    buttonForward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


    EditText edit_team = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_team);
    EditText edit_form = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_form);
    EditText edit_import = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_import);       
    String ekipa1 = edit_team.getText().toString();

    final double input2 = Double.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating()); 
    final double input3 = Double.valueOf(edit_form.getText().toString());
    final double input4 = Double.valueOf(mplayerControl.getProgress());
    final double input6 = Double.valueOf(edit_import.getText().toString());

    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Value",input2);
    intent.putExtra("Value1",input3);
    intent.putExtra("Value2",input4);
    intent.putExtra("Value3",**input5**);
    intent.putExtra("Value4",input6);
    intent.putExtra("team1", ekipa1);
    startActivity(intent);


            }       
    });
    }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what variable scope is ?!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `input5` as a instance-member

```
  if(isChecked){
             **double input5 = 1;**
            }else{
             **double input5 = 2;**
            }
```

It is declared and initialized in the if else block (input 5 is local to if else block).

If you have already declared as instance-member then initialize the variable `input5`.

```
 if(isChecked){
             input5 = 1;
            }else{
             input5 = 2;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Was strugling with this switch for days because of this silly mistake :))

Comment: @user3041073 you are welcome. mark the answer as accepted if it helps by clicking the tick once

Comment: I consider using a class-variable as bad style and will lead to unexpected behaviour if you have more instances of that activity. If you want to save the state of this simple component you should use instance-variables. On top of that I wouldn't store this simple state in a variable since the component itself stores it. So -1 for using class-variable.

Comment: @AlexS.  If you downvoted, you are mistaken and should undo it.  A class variable IS an instance variable unless you define it as static.  You can create as many instances of this Activity as you like with `input5` declared as Raghunandan has stated with no side effects.

Comment: @Simon Class-variables is a general term used in object-oriented-design whereas static is a keyword in some OO-languages as Java. I downvoted because this post may cause a lot of confusion with standard terms. See [class-variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). So I'm not mistaken: Class variables are declared using the static keyword in Java.

Comment: @AlexS the word class variable may be misleading. but downvote was not warranted could have edited my post and i never mentioned static keyword anywhere. "On top of that I wouldn't store this simple state in a variable since the component itself stores it". i would leave it to op to decide that. I only pointed out the mistake

Comment: @AlexS you are arguing over semantics.  If `static` had been suggested, I might agree with you.  As it is, the proposed solution is a common pattern and has no ambiguity or side effects.  Your downvote is not good.

Comment: @Raghunandan I know you didn't mention static. But class-member means using static-keyword in Java and thus I think of your solution as very bad example. If you'd just remove the class in your post, I'd revoke my downvote.

Comment: @AlexS i did i edited of i you feel you can put it in a better way feel free to edit my post

Comment: @Simon Semantics is of crucial importance to programming and using clear semantics is the best way to enable teamwork and to help people learning something. And as I quoted static and class-member is equivalent.

Comment: @Raghunandan I made minor changes to your post. As soon as they are accepted I will undo my downvote.

Comment: @Raghunandan What are you trying to say with that link? The discusion wasn't about variable, field or parameter but about class- and instance-scope. By the way: the "I wouldn't store the state" was of course not the reason for downvoting. I hope you understood my main point.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is going out of scope. I don't think that you need to create the onCheckChanged listener like you are at the moment. You can query the isChecked() function on the Switch directly from your Button's onClick listener, when you are creating the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

All your variables are declared in a method, which means they can only be accessed inside this method.

Therefor input2, inpu3, input4 and input6 are only accessable in your onClick() and input5 is only accessable inside onCheckedChanged().

Try this:

```
final Switch mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.edit_home);

final double input2 = Double.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating()); 
final double input3 = Double.valueOf(edit_form.getText().toString());
final double input4 = Double.valueOf(mplayerControl.getProgress());
final double input5 = (mySwitch.isChecked() ? 1.0 : 2.0);
final double input6 = Double.valueOf(edit_import.getText().toString());
```